# сложение чисел с плавающей запятой. подробное решение

Tags: c#

Я новичок в с#, не могли бы вы подсказать, как написать программу, чтобы она выводила полное решение для сложения двоичных чисел с плавающей запятой(точкой). Сам что то сильно много времени провозился, а результата никакого.

К примеру создал программу:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static char[] delim = new[] { '.', ',' };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] allowedChars = new[] { '0', '1' }.Concat(delim).ToArray();
            string[] data = new string[2];
            for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
            {
                Console.Write("Введите число №{0} в двоичной системе счисления: ", n + 1);
                data[n] = Console.ReadLine();
                bool hasDelim = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < data[n].Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!allowedChars.Contains(data[n][i]))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка. Неверные данные. Символ '{0}' не может присутствовать в числе в двоичной системе счисления.\nНажмите любую клавишу для выхода из программы.", data[n][i]);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (delim.Contains(data[n][i]))
                        if (!hasDelim)
                            hasDelim = true;
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка. В числе не может быть больше одного десятичного разделителя.\nНажмите любую клавишу для выхода из программы.");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            return;
                        }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Данные верные");
            Console.WriteLine("Сумма чисел: {0}", From10To2(GetValue(data[0]) + GetValue(data[1])));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // из строки в десятичное число
        static double GetValue(string input)
        {
            input = input.Trim(delim);
            double retVal = 0;
            double pow = input.Split(delim)[0].Length - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
                if (delim.Contains(input[i]))
                    continue;
                else
                    retVal += Math.Pow(2, pow--) * Convert.ToDouble(input[i].ToString());
            return retVal;
        }

        // Из double в двоичное число
        static string From10To2(double input)
        {
            string retval = "";
            // Отделяем целую и дробную части
            string[] data = input.ToString().Split(delim);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(data[0]);
            do
                // Запоминаем остаток от деления на 2
                sb.Append(a % 2);
            // продолжаем деление, пока число больше 1
            while ((a = a / 2) > 1);
            // запоминаем последнее число
            sb.Append(a);
            retval += String.Join("", sb.ToString().Reverse().ToArray());
            sb.Clear();
            // есть дробная часть
            if (data.Length > 1)
            {
                sb.Append(".");
                double d = input;
                d -= (int)d;
                while ((d = (d - (int)d) * 2) != 0)
                    sb.Append((int)d);
            }
            return retval + sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Но как показать изменение мантиссы и порядка не понимаю

P.S.  После подсказки я записал программу так

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;

 namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class DoubleInfo
 {
public long Mantissa;
public int Exponent;
public bool IsNegative;

public override string ToString()
{
    return
        "Mantissa: {Mantissa:X8}, Exponent: {Exponent}, " +
        "Sign: {(IsNegative ? '-' : '+')}";
}
    }

    class Program
 {
static DoubleInfo ExtractInfo(double d)
{
    if (double.IsInfinity(d) || double.IsNaN(d))
        return null;

    var result = new DoubleInfo();
    long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d);

    result.IsNegative = bits < 0;
    result.Exponent = (int) ((bits >> 52) & 0x7ffL);
    result.Mantissa = bits & 0xfffffffffffffL;

    if (result.Exponent == 0) // субнормальные числа
        result.Exponent++;
    else // нормальные числа, добавляем ведущий бит
        result.Mantissa = result.Mantissa | (1L << 52);

    result.Exponent -= 1023; // экспонента сдвинута на 1023
    return result;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double d1 = 2.1;
    double d2 = 2;
    double diff = d1 - d2;
    Console.WriteLine("d1     : {ExtractInfo(d1)}");
    Console.WriteLine("d2     : {ExtractInfo(d2)}");
    Console.WriteLine("d1 - d2: {ExtractInfo(diff)}");
}
}
}
```

но почему-то данная программа результат не выдает. Подскажите, в чем ошибка

Comment: Полное решение - это отдельное отображение каждого изменённого бита? Лучше уж так, чем подробное описание полустрочки кода...

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "полное решение ... (и далее по тексту)"?

Comment: Как изменялась мантисса и порядок

Comment: Обычно говорят "мантисса и экспонента". Под "порядком" вы имеете ввиду экспоненту?

Comment: да, точно, именно так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, вам нужно что-то такое:

```
class DoubleInfo
{
    public long Mantissa;
    public int Exponent;
    public bool IsNegative;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return
            $"Mantissa: {Mantissa:X8}, Exponent: {Exponent}, " +
            $"Sign: {(IsNegative ? '-' : '+')}";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static DoubleInfo ExtractInfo(double d)
    {
        if (double.IsInfinity(d) || double.IsNaN(d))
            return null;

        var result = new DoubleInfo();
        long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d);

        result.IsNegative = bits < 0;
        result.Exponent = (int) ((bits >> 52) & 0x7ffL);
        result.Mantissa = bits & 0xfffffffffffffL;

        if (result.Exponent == 0) // субнормальные числа
            result.Exponent++;
        else // нормальные числа, добавляем ведущий бит
            result.Mantissa = result.Mantissa | (1L << 52);

        result.Exponent -= 1023; // экспонента сдвинута на 1023
        return result;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double d1 = 2.1;
        double d2 = 2;
        double diff = d1 - d2;
        Console.WriteLine($"d1     : {ExtractInfo(d1)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"d2     : {ExtractInfo(d2)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"d1 - d2: {ExtractInfo(diff)}");
    }
}
```

Выдаёт:

```
d1     : Mantissa: 10CCCCCCCCCCCD, Exponent: 1, Sign: +
d2     : Mantissa: 10000000000000, Exponent: 1, Sign: +
d1 - d2: Mantissa: 199999999999A0, Exponent: -4, Sign: +
```

Читайте, разбирайтесь.

Comment: извиняюсь, я может неправильно понял, но когда я использую этот код, программа вообще не работает. Пожалуйста поясните

Comment: то есть синтаксис вроде правильный, но программа не запускается

Comment: @J.New: О какой программе вы говорите? О той, которая в моём примере, или о вашей?

Comment: О том, которая на вашем примере

Comment: @J.New: Странно. Вот же работает на ideone: http://ideone.com/c7u8fp

Comment: но она же не складывает двоичные

Comment: или может мне каким то способом подставить  ваше решение в свою программу?

Comment: @J.New: Она складывает (ну, в моём случае вычитает) числа типа `double`, и выводит их мантиссу/порядок. Разве это не то, что вам нужно?